# BCELoss between logits and labels not working

Tags: pytorch, nlp, loss-function, text-classification, gpt-2

I am using a GPT2 model that outputs `logits` (before softmax) in the shape `(batch_size, num_input_ids, vocab_size)` and I need to compare it with the labels that are of shape `(batch_size, num_input_ids)` to calculate BCELoss. How do I calculate it?

```
logits = output.logits #--of shape (32, 56, 592)
logits = torch.nn.Softmax()(logits)
labels = labels #---------of shape (32, 56)

torch.nn.BCELoss()(logits, labels)
```

but the dimensions do not match, so how do I contract `logits` to `labels` shape or expand `labels` to `logits` shape?

Comment: Are the labels binary, i.e., 0-1? Then why does logit has shape 592? If these shapes are correct, then why are your using BinaryCrossEntropy loss?

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without understanding what each dimension represents.  Is it batch x feature x channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Binary cross-entropy** is used when the final classification layer is a **sigmoid layer**, i.e., for each output dimension, only a true/false output is possible. You can imagine it as assigning some tags to the input. This also means that the `labels` need to have the same dimension as the `logits`, having 0/1 for each logit. Statistically speaking, for 592 output dimensions, you predict 592 Bernoulli (= binary) distributions. The expected shape is 32 × 56 × 592.

When using the **softmax layer**, you assume only one target class is possible; you predict a single categorical distribution over 592 possible output classes. However, in this case, the correct loss function is not binary cross-entropy but **categorical cross-entropy**, implemented by the [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) class in PyTorch. Note that it takes the logits directly before the softmax normalization and does the normalization internally. The expected shape is 32 × 56, as in the code snippet.

Comment: This makes sense. I one-hot encoded the `labels` onto the `vocab_size` so the dimensions of `labels` are the same as `logits`. Then calculated `CrossEntropyLoss` between them. Does that sound correct?

Comment: No, you eithe use one-hot labels with BCE or integer labels with cross-entropy.